# How do I get my menu to centre on all displays

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/aw4zgwso/

Here's what's happening at the moment and I can't seem to center the nav menu unless I add something like `width:40%` to `.menu` But that doesn't work well and will knock the text down on smaller resolution displays

```css
.nav { 
  width:100%; 
  height:40px; 
  display:block; 
  background-color:#313131;
}

.nav_inner {
  height:100%; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  position:relative;
}


.nav_menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;

}

.nav_menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav_menu li a {
  display: block;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_menu a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
  margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
}

.menu a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:0%;
  color:#00AAFF; 
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size:16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding:9px 40px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background:#191919;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index:1;
  opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
  width:160%;
  padding:5px 0px;
  position:absolute;
  top:95%;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
  background:#313131;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display:block;
  font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding:10px 30px;
  display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background:#191919;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_inner">
        <nav class="hide-mobile menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">About us<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="technology-partners.html">Technology Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">IT Solutions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="audio-visual.html">Audio Visual</a></li>
                        <li><a href="backup-replication-business-continuity.html">Backup, Replication and 
      <li><a href="visitor-and-entry-management.html">Visitor &amp; Entry Management</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox makes achieving this type of layout much simpler - if IE9 support is not a consideration, you might want to take a look at that approach (even if IE9 is a consideration, you might be able to use a polyfill or have a non-flex fallback for older browsers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `text-align:center` and make `li` **inline-block** like this :

```
.menu>ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

here is the full code

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #313131;
}

.nav_inner {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.nav_menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav_menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_menu a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/*----- Menu Outline -----*/

.menu-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #3e3436;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover>a,
.menu .current-item>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0%;
  color: #00AAFF;
  padding-left: 5px;
}


/*----- Top Level -----*/

.menu>ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 9px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu>ul>li:hover>a,
.menu>ul>.current-item>a {
  background: #191919;
}


/*----- Bottom Level -----*/

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 160%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  background: #313131;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #191919;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav_inner">

    <nav class="hide-mobile menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">

        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">About us<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
            <li><a href="technology-partners.html">Technology Partners</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">IT Solutions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="audio-visual.html">Audio Visual</a></li>
            <li><a href="backup-replication-business-continuity.html">Backup, Replication and 
       <li><a href="visitor-and-entry-management.html">Visitor &amp; Entry Management</a></li>
          </ul>

        </li>



        <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh damn it I knew it would be something this simple! Thank you friend.

Comment: @SaturnsEye, yes ;) using `inline-block` and `text-align` is very easy to control horizontal alignement

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
ul {
    text-align: center; 
}
.menu > ul > li {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: i think you need to elaborate more the answer, as making `float:none` isn't enough, you need to specify the display also. Consider adding a working code so we can see the result ;)

Comment: don't be sorry,  I am simply advicing you to have better answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Set `text-align: center;` for parent(`.menu`) and `display: inline-block;` for children(`.clearfix`).

```
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
}

.menu li {
    bottom: 12px;
    //more code...
}
```

```css
.nav { width:100%; height:40px; display:block; background-color:#313131;}

.nav_inner {height:100%; margin:0 auto; position:relative;}


.nav_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 15px;
    
}

.nav_menu li {
    float: left;
}

.nav_menu li a {
    display: block;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_menu a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}



.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
 
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    background:#3e3436;
}
 
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
}

.menu li {
    bottom: 12px;
    list-style:none;

}
 
.menu a {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}
 
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:0%;
    color:#00AAFF;  
    padding-left: 5px;
}
 
/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
 
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:9px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
}
 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#191919;
}
 
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
 
.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:95%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    background:#313131;
}
 
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}
 
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}
 
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#191919;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_inner"> 
        
        <nav class="hide-mobile menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
            
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">About us<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
     
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="technology-partners.html">Technology Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>
                
                </li>           
                
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">IT Solutions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                
                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="audio-visual.html">Audio Visual</a></li>
                            <li><a href="backup-replication-business-continuity.html">Backup, Replication and 
                            <li><a href="visitor-and-entry-management.html">Visitor &amp; Entry Management</a></li>
                    </ul>
                
                </li>
                
                
                        
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the menu you just need to add this CSS to your menu. I'm diffinatly sure it's helpful for you.

```css
.menu ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.nav { 
  width:100%; 
  height:40px; 
  display:block; 
  background-color:#313131;
}

.nav_inner {
  height:100%; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  position:relative;
}


.nav_menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;

}

.nav_menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav_menu li a {
  display: block;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_menu a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
  margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
}

.menu a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:0%;
  color:#00AAFF; 
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size:16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding:9px 40px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background:#191919;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index:1;
  opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
  width:160%;
  padding:5px 0px;
  position:absolute;
  top:95%;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
  background:#313131;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display:block;
  font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding:10px 30px;
  display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background:#191919;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_inner">
        <nav class="hide-mobile menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">About us<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="technology-partners.html">Technology Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">IT Solutions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="audio-visual.html">Audio Visual</a></li>
                        <li><a href="backup-replication-business-continuity.html">Backup, Replication and 
      <li><a href="visitor-and-entry-management.html">Visitor &amp; Entry Management</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `text-align: center` to horizontally center nested elements

If you declare `text-align: center` on the containing parent element (`.menu > ul`), remove any arbitrary `margin` or `padding` that may offset horizontal alignment, and remove the `float` rule declared on the list items (`li`) - you should achieve the intended result.

**Note:** for horizontal alignment, using `text-align: center` to work as expected, a few requirements should be met:

1. The containing parent element must be a *block* element (e.g:
   `display: block`)
2. The nested elements you need centered should be *inline-block*
   elements (e.g: `display: inline-block`)
3. No `float` rules should be declared on the nested elements you are
   intending to horizontally align, `float` rules will negate any effort
   to align elements in this way

```css
.nav { 
  width:100%; 
  height:40px; 
  display:block; 
  background-color:#313131;
}

.nav_inner {
  height:100%; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  position:relative;
}


.nav_menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;

}

/* Additional */
.menu > ul {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px; /* remove arbitrary padding */
    text-align: center;
}
/* end Additional */

.nav_menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav_menu li a {
  display: block;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_menu a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
  margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
}

.menu a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:0%;
  color:#00AAFF; 
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
  float:none; /* remove float */
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size:16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding:9px 40px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background:#191919;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index:1;
  opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
  width:160%;
  padding:5px 0px;
  position:absolute;
  top:95%;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
  background:#313131;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display:block;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align: left; /* retain left text-alignment on submenu list items */
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding:10px 30px;
  display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background:#191919;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_inner">
        <nav class="hide-mobile menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">About us<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="technology-partners.html">Technology Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">IT Solutions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="audio-visual.html">Audio Visual</a></li>
                        <li><a href="backup-replication-business-continuity.html">Backup, Replication and 
      <li><a href="visitor-and-entry-management.html">Visitor &amp; Entry Management</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or... you could *Just use Flex*...

#### Using `flex-box` to horizontally center nested elements

By declaring `display: flex` on a parent element and `justify-content: center` you will be able to horizontally center elements. `flex-box` is actually great for *list items* specifically since it usually required specific nested children, e.g: *ordered* (`ol`) or *unordered* (`ul`) lists only accept `li` elements as directly nested children for valid markup, and `flex-box` typically has a parent-to-direct-child "dependency" (so in other words, `flex-box` rules work great for directly nested children, but may adversely affect other elements nested deeper in/down the DOM tree in ways you are either not anticipating or do not desire).

```
/* Additional */
.menu > ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**See collapsed Code Snippet below demonstrating `flex-box` solution**

```css
.nav { 
  width:100%; 
  height:40px; 
  display:block; 
  background-color:#313131;
}

.nav_inner {
  height:100%; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  position:relative;
}


.nav_menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 15px;

}

/* Additional */
.menu > ul {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
}
/* end Additional */

.nav_menu li {
  float: left;
}

.nav_menu li a {
  display: block;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_menu a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}

.clearfix:after {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
  width:100%;
  background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
  margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin:0px;
  list-style:none;
}

.menu a {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:0%;
  color:#00AAFF; 
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size:16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
  padding:9px 40px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
  background:#191919;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index:1;
  opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
  width:160%;
  padding:5px 0px;
  position:absolute;
  top:95%;
  left:0px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
  background:#313131;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display:block;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align: left; /* retain left text-alignment on submenu list items */
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding:10px 30px;
  display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
  background:#191919;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_inner">
        <nav class="hide-mobile menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">About us<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="technology-partners.html">Technology Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">IT Solutions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="audio-visual.html">Audio Visual</a></li>
                        <li><a href="backup-replication-business-continuity.html">Backup, Replication and 
      <li><a href="visitor-and-entry-management.html">Visitor &amp; Entry Management</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Heads up!** `flex-box` has poor or limited support for legacy browsers, so if this is going to be a concern for you, it's probably better not to use it in production.

IE <= 9 - *Not Supported*
IE 10,11 - *Partial Support*
**See more:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

/HTML/

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav_inner"> 

        <nav class="hide-mobile menu">
            <ul class="navs">

                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">About us<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="our-values.html">Our Values</a></li>
                        <li><a href="technology-partners.html">Technology Partners</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>           

                <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">IT Solutions<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>

                   <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="audio-visual.html">Audio Visual</a></li>
                            <li><a href="backup-replication-business-continuity.html">Backup, Replication and 
                            <li><a href="visitor-and-entry-management.html">Visitor &amp; Entry Management</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>



                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

.nav { width:100%;display:block; text-align:center;background-color:#313131;}

```
.nav_inner {height:100%; margin:0 auto; position:relative;text-align:center}


.nav_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

    line-height: 15px;

}

.nav_menu li {
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav_menu li a {
    display: block;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_menu a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}

.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
    margin:0px auto;
}


.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
}

.menu a {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#ffffff;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:0%;
    color:#00AAFF;  
    padding-left: 5px;
}
 .navs {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {

    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:16px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:9px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#191919;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:95%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    background:#313131;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#191919;
}
```